# how to make a micropython submodule

Tags: c++, python-3.x, micropython

I made a python module using micropython in cpp as per the following guidelines :-
https://micropython-dev-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding-module.html

lets say I have a module named A such as in the environment I use it as

```
import A
print(A.disp())
```

now, I wish to make another module B which acts as a submodule of the module A.
Such that in the IDE it should works as follows :-

```
import A
print(A.B.view())
```

any suggestions??

Comment: This is a bit broad / lacking information. You can do this in Python (i.e. wrap the cpp module module in a Python module A, and in A's `__init__.py` you just use `from my_cpp_module import *` and `import B`) or in C (something like `mp_obj_dict_store(my_module_dict, qstr("B"), mp_builtin___import__(argsformoduleB))` in pseudocode)

Comment: Are you still following this question?